# Random Access file seek operation line by line in java

Tags: java

I have large text file in a sorted form. I want to search records  and insert new record in this file. For searching binarySearch looks better choice but to implement binary search I need a seek operation which will works on line number(Random Access File seek operation works on offset or byte length in java) Please guide me what will the better alternative to perform search operation in sorted file using java.

Comment: And I believe record size is same in all the lines of this file right?

Comment: it's not necessary.If the record size of each row is same then it is easy by multiplying size to line number to get actual offset position

Answer (score 0):

You could always implement a binary search with line->byte indexing, such that you know what offset to jump to...